# Polynomial or Theory of Equations Book with Well Described Theory and Many examples and Good Exercise

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want some Books on Polynomials or Theory of Equations which have well described theory. It has many examples from easy (Beginner Level) to hard (PUTNAM level). In the exercise there are so many problems from easy to hard. I want such books for olympiads, College entrance exams.

Comment: What level are you looking for? Most books on polynomials tend to be a bit more abstract (more about rings than polynomials themselves)

Comment: I am not beginner. In India I am in almost Regional Mathematics Olympiad Level. I am neither good nor bad at it. Check the recent questions from here to know my level I would say. I cant describe it properly. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3311_regional_mathematical_olympiad

Comment: I don't know how your AOPS profile is supposed to help me, but I guess that the best beginner treatment of polynomials is the second section of Dummit and Foote. The theory and the problems are great, but they aren't competition problems, so be warned. Also, not all of the problems are polynomial problems.

Comment: I am not giving you my aops profile. I am sharing which level of problems i am used to in polynomials